# Parsec - 'many' and error messages

Tags: haskell, parsec

When I try to parse  `many p`, I don't receive the 'expecting p' message:

```
> parse (many (char '.') >> eof) "" "a"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected 'a'
expecting end of input
```

Compare to

```
> parse (sepBy (char '.') (char ',') >> eof) "" "a"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected 'a'
expecting "." or end of input
```

which reports "." as I'd expect. `many1 p <|> return []` works as well.

**All of these functions accept empty input**, so why doesn't `many` report what it's expecting? Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a somewhat superficial sense, the reason for the difference in behavior is that `many` is a [primitive parser](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.0/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#many) whereas `sepBy` is constructed [in a similar manner](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.0/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#sepBy) to your reimplemented `many`. In the latter case, the "expecting..." message is constructed based on alternatives that were available along the path that led to the parse failure; with `many` there were no such choices, it merely succeeded unconditionally.

I don't know that I'd describe this as either a bug *or* a feature, it's just sort of a quirk of how Parsec works. Error handling is not really Parsec's strength and this really doesn't seem like the first thing I'd worry about in that regard. If it bothers you sufficiently you may be better served by looking into other parsing libraries. I've heard good things about [uu-parsinglib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib), for instance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a hidden implementation detail? `many` could also be defined using `<|>`, and from what I see it wasn't defined this way for performance reasons.

Comment: @hmp: Probably should be, yes. Though I expect you'd be better off supplying your own message with `(<?>)` in either case.

Answer (score 8):

You'll get better error messages with `manyTill`:

```
> parse (manyTill (char '.') eof) "" "a"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected 'a'
expecting end of input or "."
```

This is just due to the way you chain with `>>`. If the first parser succeeds, then the second one will be run. `many` succeeds, so `eof` is tried. `eof` fails so you only get `eof`'s error message.

With `manyTill`, it tries both parsers (the second first) and, if both fail, the error messages are combined (this is because it uses `<|>` internally).

On the whole, though, it's easier to define your own errors with `<?>`:

```
> parse (many (char '.') >> eof <?> "lots of dots") "" "a"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected 'a'
expecting lots of dots
```

Comment: It's not due to the way I chain parsers, because other parsers (that use `<|>`) also succeed on empty input, and collect the errors. (The problem was with `between (sym "{") (sym "}") $ many stmt`, and I wanted to see "expecting '}' or statement" on errors.)

Comment: That's the point, the error messages are only for the current parser - the only reason you get "x or y" messages is because the `<|>` combinator specifically collects the messages from both sub parsers. `between` just chains with `>>` like your example. So if you write a version of between that uses `<|>` you can get "} or statement" errors. :)

Comment: For example, see the `<|>` implementation for how it merges error messages: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#parserPlus

Comment: OK, I understand why this doesn't work. But I'm not convinced why `many` not collecting errors (if it doesn't use `<|>`, it could implement that manually) is "correct". As others said, error reporting is not explicitly documented, but to me this still seems like it's breaking some contract.

Comment: Well, the problem with error reporting in your example code is that when the parse fails, the fault is not with `many`, as `many` has actually *succeeded* (it parsed nothing). After this, the `eof` parser is run, which fails. (This is what I was trying to explain in the second paragraph.) The parser never backtracks to before the `>>`. This is why I suggested using `manyTill`, because its semantics are better for this situation - using `>>` says "run the first parser, and if it succeeds then run the second unconditionally".

Answer (score 1):

From [haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3amany)

> many p applies the parser p zero or
>   more times. Returns a list of the
>   returned values of p.

So empty string is a valid input for `many` combinator.

[Added]

Ah, now I see your point. `expecting a or b` is reported when `<|>` (choice combinator) is used. `many` is implemented without using `<|>`, but `sepBy` uses it internally.

Comment: That's not the point. Empty string is also a valid input for sepBy, but sepBy reports errors from its argument.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. I was wondering whether I'm misusing the library by wanting this behavior, or if this is a bug in Parsec.

Comment: Well, error reporting is not explicitly documented (at least in haddock documentation), so it is not a 'bug'. Error reporting depends on implementation -- no guaranties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in parsec-3.1. If you test with prior versions you should get an error message like this:

```
> parse (many (char '.') >> eof) "" "a"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected 'a'
expecting "." or end of input
```

At least, that's what I get after fixing the bug :-)

Comment: I get the same error message for both parsers in my hacked up copy of parsec 3.1 and in parsec-3.0 - the behavior you mention is only in parsec-3.1. I've edited my comment.